# What are UI/UX patterns and their pros/cons for 1-to-1 assignments of items from two different sets?

Tags: user-interface, set, user-experience, assign, bipartite

Think of two different "bipartite" sets of items: vehicles and drivers. The user has to make 1-to-1 assignments between these items like so:

- Each vehicle can be assigned to 0 or 1 driver.
- Each driver can be assigned to 0 or 1 vehicle.

What would be suitable UI/UX patterns for this?

I've already thought about providing three "drag-and-drop" lists: (1) unassigned vehicles, (2) unassigned drivers, and (3) 1-to-1 assignments of vehicles and drivers. But I'm not sure about the "most comfortable" workflows/actions for creating new assignments, flipping vehicles/drivers of two assignments, managing large numbers of items, etc. with as few clicks/actions as possible. Or maybe there is a UI/UX pattern I'm not aware of at all.

Comment: Asking with _Best_ in the title will probably get you close votes, I suggest rewording to ask something like "What are UI/UX patterns and their pros/cons"?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @AndyDent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Important Gotchas

1. When you're managing multi-list selection you need to be very specific about context - is this going to be on a narrow screen such as a phone or portrait tablet? Narrow screens are often poor for side-by-side lists.
2. This sounds like quite an *industrial* application - is it done in a setting where people are standing or walking and may be jostled? Drag-n-drop can lose things half-way.

One idiom is a copy-paste variant where tapping an item in one list *selects* it and you either can tap another item, or some other *cancel zone* or tapping in the second list *pastes* the connection.

If the lists are long, offer an option to show only the *free* items so you can focus on those left to be assigned. That can be a simple toggle, maybe three-way between All/Free/Set.

Comment: Thank you. The users are expected to use the software on a desktop PC with mouse and keyboard. I actually thought about a drag-and-drop operation of one unassigned item onto the desired item from the other list. This is pretty close to your suggestion, I guess.

Comment: Based on what I already thought of plus some of your suggestions I came up with a small and simple prototype: https://jsfiddle.net/Flinsch/f0ymhv6d/